# Moving to Spain with non-EU partner

Tags: working-visas, spain, family, dependent-visa

Me and my boyfriend are both non-EU citizens (I'm a Russian citizen and he is a Colombian citizen). Currently we are living in the Netherlands with working permits as knowledge migrants and we are also registered as [partners](https://www.government.nl/topics/family-law/contents/marriage-registered-partnership-and-cohabitation-agreements), which is an equivalent of *pareja de hecho* in Spain.

I got a job offer in Barcelona, and now the company that is going to contract me started with a paperwork of getting a working visa for me.

What would be the easiest way to bring my partner with me? Can he also apply to Spanish visa based on my application?

Comment: (+1) It will not necessarily make a big difference in this case but how long have you lived in the Netherlands? After 5 years, there is a “permanent resident” status that should make it somewhat easier to move between EU countries.

Comment: @Gala I've lived here only for 7 months.

Comment: OK, so that's moot obviously :)

Comment: This is a very good question. The EU recognizes a "right to family life" but the [relevant directive](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:251:0012:0018:EN:PDF) notes that it is for member states to decide whether registered partners qualify for family reunion. The Spanish consulate in NYC does not mention registered partners, but this could be because the concept is rare in the US. I couldn't find any information on the web sites of Spain's Interior and Foreign ministries, but maybe someone who reads Spanish better than I can would be able to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short version: yes, but not for a year.

To summarise the [official guidance](http://extranjeros.empleo.gob.es/es/informacioninteres/InformacionProcedimientos/Ciudadanosnocomunitarios/hoja012/index.html) about the right to reunion for non-EU citizens:

- The person who is already resident in Spain (i.e. you) must have sufficient income to support the person who is applying to join them. To bring one family member over you need a monthly income of 800€.
- You must have resided in Spain for at least a year and have obtained authorisation to reside for at least another year.
- The usual stuff about criminal records etc.
- The right does apply to registered partners.

  > Se considera relación análoga a la conyugal:
  >
  > Cuando está inscrita en un registro público y no se haya cancelado la inscripción, o ...
- This approach would not enable your boyfriend to work legally in Spain (although if his employer in the Netherlands is happy for him to work remotely, it might be worth getting professional legal advice as to whether that is an option).

---

Other options are to check your boyfriend's genealogy very carefully to see whether he can apply for Spanish citizenship by inheritance; for him to try to find a job from the Netherlands; or for you both to hope that Cataluña separates from Spain and decides to implement a very open immigration policy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know if there is category of *highly skilled migrants* / *knowledge migrants* in Spain? (I'm asking that because we live in the Netherlands with a visa for highly skilled migrants, and that allowed us to reunion without waiting for one year).

Comment: I found [this link](http://extranjeros.empleo.gob.es/es/informacioninteres/informacionprocedimientos/Ciudadanosnocomunitarios/hoja022/index.html) where they mention family members, but I can't figure out how it works in this case.

Comment: The link you've found is indeed for visas for highly skilled workers. It only says two things about family members: a) if the employer is a physical person (i.e. as opposed to a company), and the employee has dependent family members then the employer has to make social security payments for the dependents; b) the requirements and procedure for conceding residency to family members of highly qualified professionals can be consulted in the available information about the corresponding authorisation for family reunion. I.e. no hint of special cases.